# how to build Angular source code in local?

Tags: build, angular8

Download Angular8.1 source code from the https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/8.1.x
Made a few XSS security fix in source code and try to build and output @angular/core.
In the source code root directory run the commonds:
yarn install
yarn run bazel
don's any output about the @angular/core, or @angular/cli.

Can anybody shed some light on this? thanks a lot